# Grouped List in SwiftUI importing data from swift file

Tags: arrays, swiftui-list, xcode12, grouped-list

I can create grouped lists in SwiftUI using the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Freyr / Freya's Aett")) {
                
            }
            Section(header: Text("Heimdall's Aett")) {
                
            }
            Section(header: Text("Tyr's Aett")) {
                
            }
            Section(header: Text("Additional Runes")) {
                
            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

I have a separate swift file which stores the data in Arrays but I can't get it to import into my list like I was able to when I used the following code in Storyboards.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Rune: Identifiable {
    var runeName: String
    var runeImage: String
    var runeDescription: String
    let id = UUID()
}

//MARK: - Runes Array Standard Orientation

var runeTitle = [["Freyr/Freya's Aett"], ["Heimdall's Aett"], ["Tyr's Aett"], ["Additional Runes"]]

let runesArray = [[Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: String(("Fehu")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here")],

                   [Rune(runeName: "Hagalaz", runeImage: String(("Hagalaz")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here")],

                  [Rune(runeName: "Tiwaz", runeImage: String(("Tiwaz")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here")],

                  [Rune(runeName: "Blank Rune", runeImage: String(("Blank")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here")]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a way to identify what goes in each section.
This particular way is quite inefficient because it runs through each item in the `runesArray` for each section but you can visualize what is going on and then work on your data.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SectionedList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text(runeTitle[0][0])) {
                ForEach(runesArray, id: \.id){rune in
                    if rune.runeTitle == runeTitle[0][0]{
                        Text(rune.runeName)
                    }
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text(runeTitle[1][0])) {
                ForEach(runesArray, id: \.id){rune in
                    if rune.runeTitle == runeTitle[1][0]{
                        Text(rune.runeName)
                    }
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text(runeTitle[2][0])) {
                ForEach(runesArray, id: \.id){rune in
                    if rune.runeTitle == runeTitle[2][0]{
                        Text(rune.runeName)
                    }
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text(runeTitle[3][0])) {
                ForEach(runesArray, id: \.id){rune in
                    if rune.runeTitle == runeTitle[3][0]{
                        Text(rune.runeName)
                    }
                }
            }
            //This is another way to do it.
            /*
            ForEach(0..<runeTitle.count){idx in
                Section(header: Text(runeTitle[idx][0])) {
                    
                    ForEach(runesArray, id: \.id){rune in
                        if rune.runeTitle == runeTitle[idx][0]{
                            Text(rune.runeName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            */
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
struct Rune: Identifiable {
    var runeName: String
    var runeImage: String
    var runeDescription: String
    var runeTitle: String
    let id = UUID()
}

//MARK: - Runes Array Standard Orientation

var runeTitle = [["Freyr/Freya's Aett"], ["Heimdall's Aett"], ["Tyr's Aett"], ["Additional Runes"]]

let runesArray = [Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: String(("Fehu")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here", runeTitle: runeTitle[0][0]),
                  
                  Rune(runeName: "Hagalaz", runeImage: String(("Hagalaz")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here", runeTitle: runeTitle[1][0]),
                  
                  Rune(runeName: "Tiwaz", runeImage: String(("Tiwaz")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here", runeTitle: runeTitle[2][0]),
                  
                  
                  Rune(runeName: "Blank Rune", runeImage: String(("Blank")), runeDescription: "Description Goes Here", runeTitle: runeTitle[3][0])]
```

I added `runeTitle` to your `Rune` structure.